# Capacitor Charge

Tags: capacitor

I have a very simple question to ask about charging capacitors and no matter what I put into the Google search bar it will not explain it. If I have a capacitor rated at 16 volts. If I put a continuous 9v supply into it will it store 9v or will it combine and eventually charge to its full capacity. What about an 18v supply? Thank you

Comment: The cap will charge up to the 9V you put across it.  18V poof, maybe not right away thought.

Comment: Can you please explain further

Comment: Probably you might want to learn more about basics. Like why the voltage on two components connected is the same one.

Comment: Peter explains it below but it's basically a safety rating.

Comment: read the answers to the question a few rows down... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303555/how-exactly-do-capacitors-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rated voltage of a capacitor is the maximum voltage that it can safely withstand.  If you apply a higher-than-rated voltage, the capacitor may be damaged or destroyed, as the dielectric breaks down.

A capacitor can only charge up to the applied voltage - it cannot create more voltage than is applied to it.

Comment: I will learn more next time. I was just wondering and couldn't figure this out. Thank you so much